# ffmpeg imlib2.so watermarking troubles

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I am trying to watermark a flash video, but it throws long list of 
"Unsupported Codec".

So, is flv not supported at all ? Do I need to convert it to `.avi` and watermark ?

Comment: You'll need to show us the full command line that generate this error.

Answer (score 0):

install all the externall libraries which ffmpeg support and configure it with ffmpeg when compiling from source.